# To change the display depending on the presence or absence of data

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django2.1

I want to create a button that will be displayed when the user saves data in the past.
I thought it could be done with {% if object %}, but it seemed different.

Here is the failed code.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if object %}
     <a class="btn" href="{% url 'detail' user.id %}">Check</a>
    {% else %}
     <a class="btn" href="{% url 'create' %}">Create</a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
```

```
#models.py
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I will create data in CreateView.

```
class MyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Mymodel
    form_class = MyForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        return super(MyCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('detail', kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk})
```

thank you for reading it until the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.mymodel %}
     <a class="btn" href="{% url 'detail' user.id %}">Check</a>
    {% else %}
     <a class="btn" href="{% url 'create' %}">Create</a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
```

Because, `Mymodel` and `User` has [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation, so you can get the `Mymodel` value using:

```
user.mymodel  # class name all lower case
```

And also get user data from my model using:

```
mymodel = Mymodel.objects.get(id=1)
mymodel.user
```